# How to move a folder into itself?

Tags: directory, mkdir

I have a directory

```
foo/
   bar.txt
   baz.yzw
   wun/
      a.out
```

Now, I would like to basically add a directory in between, i.e. I would like to make it

```
foo/
   var1/
      bar.txt
      baz.yzw
      wun/
         a.out
```

with the intent of also adding other stuff to `foo`, but kept separate from the old contents.

I could of course do it like this:

```
$ mkdir foo-new
$ mv foo foo-new
$ mv foo-new foo
```

or

```
$ cd foo
$ mkdir var1
$ mv $(ls | grep -v var1) var1
```

but both seem inelegant and are error-prone.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ cd foo
$ mkdir var1
$ mv * var1
```

The shell and `mv` command are smart enough to not try to move the var1 directory into itself.

Comment: I should have just tried this... easy! It feels a bit inelegant because of the error message `mv: cannot move 'var1' to a subdirectory of itself, 'foo/var1'`, but on the command-line this is clearly the way to go.

Comment: For clarity: At least on macOS this command does copy the files but the command fails (its exit code is `1` instead of `0`) and prints out the error message mentioned in the comment above, so it's not great for scripting.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply make var1 directory, move all files/folders in foo to var1 and finally move var1 inside foo

```
    $ mkdir var1 
    $ mv foo/* var1
    $ mv var1 foo/
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with renaming the directory and moving it inside a new one, approximately as you did. To insert `var1/` between `foo` and its contents:

```
d=$(mktemp -d ./tmp.XXXXXX)
mkdir "$d"; mv foo "$d"/var1; mv "$d" foo
```

That works for the directory contents. However, it's a bit more complicated if we also consider the owner, access bits, ACLs, extended attributes, inode number etc. of the directory.

If we want to keep `foo` intact, then we'll need to create `var1` anew, and move the contents. Using Bash:

```
cd foo
mkdir var1
shopt -s dotglob    # to get any dotfiles
mv * var1           # ignore the error about moving var1 to itself
```

Or, to avoid the error, use `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob 
mv !(var1) var1
```

---

Note that `$(ls | grep -v)` will not include dotfiles, and it will not work if you have filenames with whitespace or newlines (for two different reasons).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rsync` which will create the destination directory (only last level) if that doesn't already exist, but this will result empty directories which you will delete it later or keep.

```
rsync -rv [--remove-source-files] foo/* foo/var1
```

There is an option `-m, --prune-empty-dirs.` that *`prune empty directory chains from file-list`* in my *rsync* man page, but I didn't get that work!

I put `--remove-source-files` within braces to be **[warn]** about that.

to delete empty directories:

```
find foo/ -depth -type d -empty -execdir rmdir "{}" \;
```